# Construct a list from two other lists of unequal length

Tags: list-manipulation

Given two lists of unequal length:

```
ind = Range[0, 4];

color = {"red", "green", "blue", "black"};
```

how can I produce efficiently the following list which is as long as the shorter of the two?

```
{{"red", 0}, {"green", 1}, {"blue", 2}, {"black", 3}}
```

Comment: Use `Transpose`.

Comment: @C.E. Thanks for the comment but the lists do not have the same length.

Comment: ok, I missed that. Then you have to shorten the first list to match the length of the second list. You could for example use `Transpose[{color, Take[ind, Length[color]]}`.

Comment: @C.E. Thanks again. I was wondering if there is a built-in function that "understands" that the two lists have different lengths and combines them in the proper manner, like `zip` function in Python.

Comment: To closers: I think this is a legitimate question given that the lists are of unequal length.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some ideas:

```
Partition[Riffle[color, ind, {2, -1, 2}], 2]

Flatten[{color, ind}, {2}] // Cases[{_, _}]

{color, PadRight[ind, Length@color]}\[Transpose]

ind ~Riffle~ color ~Partition~ 2 ~Reverse~ 2

MapIndexed[{#, Extract[ind, #2]} &, color]

Take[#, All, Min[Length /@ #]]\[Transpose] &[{color, ind}]
```

All produce:

> ```
> {{"red", 0}, {"green", 1}, {"blue", 2}, {"black", 3}}
> ```

I'll note that the last method, which was perhaps my most serious attempt to answer this pragmatically, can be applied to any number of lists:

```
fn = Take[#, All, Min[Length /@ #]]\[Transpose] &;

fn[{{1, 2, 3}, Alphabet[], 2^Range@5}]
```

> ```
> {{1, "a", 2}, {2, "b", 4}, {3, "c", 8}}
> ```

Comment: You have once again lived up to your username.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function to do it for any two lists. It doesn't care about the order in which the lists appear as arguments.

```
makePairs[a_List, b_List] :=
  Transpose[Take[#, Min[{Length @ a, Length @ b}]] & /@ {a, b}]
```

```
makePairs[color, ind]
```

> `{{"red", 0}, {"green", 1}, {"blue", 2}, {"black", 3}}`

```
makePairs[ind, color]
```

> `{{"red", 0}, {"green", 1}, {"blue", 2}, {"black", 3}}`

Comment: FWIW that's pretty similar to my last method: `Take[#, All, Min[Length /@ #]]\[Transpose] &`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. The methods might be similar, but the programming philosophy illustrated by the two answer differ enough that I think this deserves to stand.

Comment: You mean you're not a fan of the shotgun answer? :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I like shotgun answers. I also think there should be room for other kinds.

Comment: No argument from me on that point!

Answer (score 4):

Another variant:

```
DeleteCases[
 Transpose[PadRight[{color, ind}, Automatic, Missing]], {___, 
  Missing, ___}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Block[{i = 1}, {#, ind[[i++]]} & /@ color]
```

> {{"red", 0}, {"green", 1}, {"blue", 2}, {"black", 3}}