# Using slot and application to variable length vector

Tags: functions, slot

I have a list of 2D coordinates with a maximum length of 3, e.g.

```
peakdatAB
{{1007.81, 8.64842}, {1008.38, 8.19264}}
```

I need to generate something like this

```
({PointSize[0.01], Blue, Point[#1], Red, Point[#2], Black, Point[#3]}) & @@ peakdatAB
```

but here the problem is the variable length of peakdatAB as when there is say no third point, it returns an error.
How can I fix this?

Comment: As long as you have enough colours `colours = {Blue, Red, Black};`  then `({PointSize[0.01], MapIndexed[{colours[[First[#2]]], Point[#1]} &, peakdatAB]})`

Comment: Another way: `Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], Riffle[colours[[;; Length[peakdatAB]]], Point /@ peakdatAB]}]`

Comment: [Duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139255/construct-a-list-from-two-other-lists-of-unequal-length).

Comment: Thanks, flinty The first one works great!